# Specify different unique key in Dexie database schema?

Tags: javascript, indexeddb, dexie

My basic dexie database scheme is something like this.

```
const db = new Dexie('MyDatabase');

// Declare tables, IDs and indexes
db.version(1).stores({
    myrecords: 'record_id'
});
```

I want to use my `record_id` as a unique key. In indexeddb I can do this like the below

```
 var myrecordsObjectStore = db.createObjectStore('myrecords' , {
                                keyPath: 'record_id'
                            });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Should work using `&` prefix for unique as noted in docs

```
db.version(1).stores({
    myrecords: '&record_id'
});
```

See [Dexie Quick Reference](https://dexie.org/docs/API-Reference#quick-reference)